# django test fail to build foreign key relationship with hidden related_name

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I have two models:

```
class Model1(BaseModel):
    hidden = models.ForeignKey(
        Model2, 
        default=10,
        related_name='+',
    )

class Model2(models.Model):
    # model content
```

so the issue is, when using django test, the test database cannot create the relationship between `Model1` and `Model2`, I suspect it's because of the field `related_name='+'` . Not sure what is the work around for this without changing the `related_name`.

the fail info is

```
  File "/app/src/save.py", line 317, in save_app
    model1.object.save()
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 740, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 778, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 881, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 921, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "Model1" violates foreign key constraint "Model1_hidden_1ba57f04_fk_Model2"
DETAIL:  Key (Model1_hidden_id)=(10) is not present in table "Model2".
```

Comment: Please add the failing test code and output to your question

Comment: This has nothing to do with `related_name`, you're trying to create a `Model1` with the hidden foreign key referencing  `Model2` with id 10 which doesn't exist. You should show your code that is trying to create the `Model1` causing the error and/or post the full traceback

Comment: this only comes up during django test, and only the model with foreinkey has `related_name="+"` has this issue. so i'm thinking it's when django building the test database, this foreignkey was not built properly, causing it cannot find the key in the table.

Comment: The issue is most likely the default - `default=10`. Without the full traceback it's impossible to know where this error is being triggered. Is the error occurring while applying migrations to the test database?

Comment: What is this `/app/src/save.py` file and `save_app` function? Where is it being called? Can you share the function?

Comment: hey @IainShelvington I used fixture to pre populate the database, and the issue is gone. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by pre-populate the testing database by using the [`fixture`](https://django-testing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fixtures.html) option. `related_name="+"` is not the real issue. real issue is the database needs to be populated before the test.